# How can I get href with selenium python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I have **python** code. I need it to **pass** **divs** and get **URLs** and **names** from each account.

Here you see all **divs** it should **pass**
[image: Here you see all divs I need to pass]

This is how it looks inside. I need to take **href** (on screenshot it looks like ***"/i.amtired"***) and name **"Владислава Безгузова"**

[image: This is how it looks inside. I need to take href (on screenshot it looks like "/i.amtired") and name "Владислава Безгузова"]

I have a **loop**, which looks like:

```
for i in range(friends_count):
    found = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div[class*=friends_list_bl]>div")))
```

It pass each div on the first screenshot.

Comment: Screenshots of the UI are great, screenshots of code or HTML are not. Please read why [a screenshot of code/HTML is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Paste the code/HTML as text and properly format it instead.

Answer (score 1):

Use below `css selector` to uniquely identify each `anchor` tag.

Use `elelemnt.text` to get the `text` of the element.
Use `element.get_attribute("href")` to get the `Href` value.

```
for a in WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div[class^='friends_user_row'] div[class^='friends_user_info'] a"))):
   print(a.text)
   print(a.get_attribute("href"))
```